# How to place spaces in between input textfield

Tags: java, charat

I am trying to place spaces in between a number that has been entered in a textfield. I am using the following code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        char cijfer = tf1.getText().charAt(i);
        char getal1 = tf1.getText().charAt(0);
        char getal2 = tf1.getText().charAt(1);
        char getal3 = tf1.getText().charAt(2);
    }

    String uitvoerGetal = getal1 + " " + getal2 + " " + getal3;
```

I suppose I don't understand the `charAt()` function yet, does anyone have a link explaining it in a way so I might be able to make this work too? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well assigning your concatenated `String` to an `int` variable won't help. Try having a look at the JavaDoc of the involved classes, it is quite good. Maybe also using a tutorial is a good 1st step.

Comment: Where are you using `cijfer`? Do not do a loop to access the elements with magic numbers.

Comment: Got it! Thank everyone for the comments, they have helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Example:

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String s = "Strings are immutable";
      char result = s.charAt(8);
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

**This produces the following result:**

```
a
```

In more Detail **From java docs**

```
public char charAt(int index)

Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges from 0 to length() - 1. The first char value of the sequence is at index 0, the next at index 1, and so on, as for array indexing.

If the char value specified by the index is a surrogate, the surrogate value is returned.

Specified by:
    charAt in interface CharSequence
Parameters:
    index - the index of the char value.
Returns:
    the char value at the specified index of this string. The first char value is at index 0.
Throws:
    IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index argument is negative or not less than the length of this string.
```

Answer (score 1):

In straight words You can't. You can't add space in `int` datatype because `int` is meant to store the integer value only. Change `int` to `String` to store the space in between.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's see what's wrong with your code...

1. Your for-loop is 1-based instead of the standard 0-based. That's not good at all.
2. You're attempting to assign a char to a String (3 times), the first call to charAt is correct, but for some reason you then switch to using a String?
3. Finally you're attempting to assign a String to an int, which is just completely nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems, but well done on an honest attempt.

- First up, the indexes in a string are zero-based, so `charAt(0)` gives you the first character, `charAt(1)` gives you the second character, and so on.
- Secondly, repeating all your calls to `charAt` three times is probably unnecessary.
- Thirdly, you must be careful with your types.  The return value from `charAt` is a `char`, not a `String`, so you can't assign it to a `String` variable.  Likewise, on the last line, don't assign a `String` to an `int` variable.
- Lastly, I don't think you've thought about what happens if the text field doesn't contain enough characters.

Bearing these points in mind, please try again, and ask for further help if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
String text = tf1.getText(); // get string from jtextfield
StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
for(int index = 0; index <text.length(); index++){
    finalString.append(text.charAt(index) + " ");  // add spaces      
}
tf1.setText(finalString.toString().trim()) // set string to jtextfield
```